# Completely suppress a program's error message boxes

Tags: windows

Whenever I play a certain fighting game offline, the following pop up appears after every single round and steals focus from the game, meaning I have to put down the controller and click the window away with my mouse every time.

[image: Error Message]

Having a little pop up telling you about errors is completely normal in most programs, but in this case, I'd like to completely suppress it. Other programs such as ImgBurn, although far less annoying, like to steal the focus away when not needed too - I'd like to prevent this.

I also feel it would be particularly useful to be able to suppress such messages while running programs that don't normally support unattended usage from a script.

Any ideas?

Comment: These pop ups always tell you some error or notification. Removing them completely or suppressing them would be a bad idea as you might be in trouble someday when you would have no idea of what's happening.

Comment: I don;t believe there is any external mechanism by which you could accomplish this. if the developer didn't make it an option, you probably aren't going to be able to pull it off.